# Choose value in one column based on value subtraction in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing 4 columns. I want to subtract the last entry of `col2` from second to last entry of `col2` and see if the subtraction of last from second to last entry is greater than 10. If so, I would like to get the corresponding value for last and second to last in first column and replace the value of second to last in first column with `NaN`, and create another dataframe as output. Is there any way i can do it in pandas?

```
col1  col2   col3   col4
 e      21      1    2
 m      20      1    2
 k      9       1    2
 j      20      1    2
```

Output:

```
col1         col3   col4
[j, 'NaN']    1      2
```

I am looking for ways based on query so that making output in the format of dataframe would become easier by applying `groupby` or `filtering`.

The code i have tried so far but it 
seems it is not working.

```
last = df.iloc[-1]['col2']
second_to_last = df.iloc[-2]['col2']

difference = df.query("{ref} - {ref_1} > 10".format(ref=last, ref_1= second_to_last))
```

The error that i am getting in line 3:

```
ValueError: multi-line expressions are only valid in the context of data
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#get last and previous index values
last = df.index[-1]
second_to_last = df.index[-2]

#boolena mask - scalar
m1 = df.loc[last, 'col2'] - df.loc[second_to_last, 'col2'] > 10
#boolean mask - array
m2 = (df.index.isin([last, second_to_last]))
#chain together
m = m1 & m2
print (m)
[False False  True  True]

#filter
df1 = df[m]
print (df1)
  col1  col2  col3  col4
2    k     9     1     2
3    j    20     1     2

#get last row, remove unnecessary column
df2 = df1.iloc[[-1]].drop('col2', axis=1)
#convert value to lsit and add missing value
df2['col1'] = df2['col1'].apply(lambda x: list(x) + [np.nan])
print (df2)
       col1  col3  col4
3  [j, nan]     1     2
```

Comment: is there any way to solve it based on query, groupby, and filtering? I highly prefer not to generate the new dataframe with pd.dataframe

Comment: I have just added another column that why i am asking for more efficient way

Comment: If `col1` has float numeric value, at output your solution ended up separating the integers like `28.6` would become `2, 8, ., 6` in the list

Comment: @user8034918 - not, it means there are strings, check it `list('28.6')`

Comment: So need `df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(float)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183351/discussion-between-user8034918-and-jezrael).